# Hibernate with complex relationships and foreign keys makes loading/saving HELL

Tags: hibernate, mapping, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I'm quite new in Hibernate, and I'm hurting a problem giving me huge headaches :

I have a database using relationships with foreign keys. I created first my database with all the links represented with MySQL InnoDB. Then, I generated from MySQL Workbench all the models from the database. It looked very nice and convenient.

Getting users and its childs is really easy and fast; BUT adding an entry is getting horrible, I need to load all the parents of the new object to be able to save it because of the "org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value...".

My schema is quite normal, a user has many photos, photos have blobs and formats, user has many favorites etc... So when I want to insert a new Photo, I need to create a HUGE amount of linked object which is really annoying and complex, compare to using a simple SQL query inserting indexes like `user_id:15` but when selecting an entry getting a User Object.

I wonder what is the good way of making relationships of complex databases, when getting an object you have loaded as objects its objects like that :

```
(User Object)
{
    firstname="John",
    lastname="Doe",
    ...
    photos:[
    {
        format:"jpg",
        url:"http://wifhwofihwofihwf.com",
        ...   
    }],
    favorites:[
    { (user Object)
         firstname:"Steve",
         lastname :"Doe",...
         photos:[...]
    },...
    ]
}
```

And how is it possible to define the depth of the required response when getting a User, because we don't want something like :

```
(User Object)
    {
        ...
        favorites:[
        { (user Object)
             firstname:"Steve",
             lastname :"Doe",...
             photos:[...],
              {
                  ...
                  favorites:[
                  {
                            ...
                            favorites:[
                            {
                                 LOOONG DEPTH
                            },...
                            ]
                  },...
                  ]
    }
```

if you have some links or advices about how to manage that I would be thankful, because I can find only very dummy examples of hibernate which are not working in my case.

Cheers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't look for examples. Read [the reference manual](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/).

To limit the depth of the tree of entities, declare the associations as lazy. This is the default for toMany associations.

```
@ManyToOne(lazy = true)
private User owner;
```

To save a new Photo, if this new Photo belongs to a User, you just have to get a reference to this user. No need to load the photos of this user, or any other indirect dependency. And you don't even need to hit the database:

```
Photo photo = new Photo();
photo.setOwner((User) session.load(User.class, userId));
session.persist(photo);
```

I don't see how it is so difficult. Maybe you should elaborate with an example of you code persisting a new Photo.

Comment: I see, so you're saying that "photo.setOwner((User) session.load(User.class, userId));" won't load the user from DB ? To create a photo I have in fact 5 tables to hit. blob, formats, admin, profile, photo itself, so how do I know the order to save ? and I guess the load(Class<?>,id) loads from the PK of the hit table ? Thanks !

Comment: Unless you flush in the middle, the order shouldn't matter. The persisted entities will be written in the appropriate order by Hibernate, at flush time. Yes, session.load() uses the ID of the entity. There is a javadoc. You could read it as well.

Comment: Thanks, Yea I'll go more in the details with the javadoc, but I read books already but was still confused... thanks for your precision